# Get item value from AsyncStorage in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner and still try to learn to react native so help me!

I want to access AsyncStorage.getItem value outside the function.
I will further explain via code

**This is my code** :

`import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';`

set that value on screen1

`AsyncStorage.setItem('mobileno', JSON.stringify(MobileNo));`

try to get that value on screen 2

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('mobileno', (err, MobileNumber) => {
    let abc = MobileNumber;
    console.log("abc value " + abc)
   })


  let { MobileNo } = abc;
  console.log({MobileNo})
```

I want to access that abc value outside the function as `let { MobileNo } = abc;` but it shows the error!

**note :**  [`console.log("abc value " + abc)` works perfectlly ]

**Error**

can't find variable abc

**question**

So, how can I access that abc or that AsyncStorage value for the whole page [outside that function]; Because I want to use that value in other function too!

**In short**, I want that stored value in AsyncStorage to use it in other function.

**Thank you for contributing your precious time**

Comment: const mobileNumber =  AsyncStorage.getItem('mobileno', (err, MobileNumber) => {
    let abc = MobileNumber;
   return abc
   })

be careful though mobileNumber might not exist as this is a callback, you should use it with await async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mobileNumber: '',
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('mobileno').then((mobileNo) => {
        if(mobileNo){
            this.setState({mobileNumber: mobileNo});
            console.log(this.state.mobileNumber);
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.mobileNumber}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

In this case async/await is not necessary because `.then()` is only called after the `getItem()` function is done fetching the item.

Comment: Is my _storeData  method is right?   _storeData = async () => { try { await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:mobileno', value); } catch (error) { // Error saving data } };

Comment: Yes, you are correctly setting the item. Don't forget to call this._storeData() somewhere in your app. You are assigning a function to a variable, but that variable needs to be used so the value can be saved.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I want to getItem on componentDidMount(); Is it possible?

Comment: Updated my answer with `AsyncStorage.getItem()` inside of `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196075/discussion-between-akash-thoriya-and-raymond-mutyaba).

Answer (score 3):

In your code `abc` is called out of scope. `abc` is only declared in your callback. An alternative can be to create a class method that returns that data. I personally find the async/await syntax much cleaner and easier understand the `.then()` chains.

[docs show an example of this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('mobileno');
      if (value !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        console.log(value);
        return value;
      }
  } catch (error) {
   // Error retrieving data
  }
}
```

Comment: _storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:mobileno', value);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

Answer (score 2):

import {**AsyncStorage**} from 'react-native';

- Above **AsyncStorage** is Deprecated, Moved to React-Native-Community

you can use now

1 :- yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage

2 :- react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage

Code :-

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}

getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Link :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage